# simple server vs virtualize server performance?

Tags: node.js, apache, web-services, jetty, virtual-machine

Lets say i have 2 servers:
1 - 12 threads server
2 - 12 threads server divided to 3 systems with 4 threads each.

If i run on both servers - apache php/node or jetty, which will perform better if it should handle 12000 requests?

Will they both handle 12 requests at once so the performance will be the same?
Will the 1 server handle only one request at once and 2 server will handle 3 request at once so it will be 3 times faster?
And how node will handle it eith its event loop engine?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without complete knowledge of the system. 12000 requests in what time? Static or dynamic? Hello world or full fledged ecommerce site? The only way to know is to measure.

Comment: I want to know it in theory. The will run rhe same script. I dont want yo know what time it will take. I wsnt to which will be faster.